# Ideas for custom Specflow html reports for .NET Core

Tags: c#, html, .net-core, nunit, specflow

Difficult to find a custom html reporter for Specflow with .NET core framework.

Although Specflow plus runner SpecRun provides a decent html report but it no where close to other reports like Extent. Extent Reports do not fully support .NET core. Are there any html report frameworks which can be integrated to Specflow out of the box ? Or any custom html reports which are easy to setup may be as in hooks configuration rather than editing each step definition or page methods?

I am using Nunit to run the tests and I would like to skip using Specflow plus runner, as it seems to have some issues running inside docker.

Comment: [Check out ReportGenerator](https://github.com/danielpalme/ReportGenerator) it has some different outputs for the reports, one of them being Html. Usage is pretty simple as well.